# Minor typo(ish) in the non-meta FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-faq

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#notation) section of the FAQ the Mathjax code is missing the `$` symbols ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fixed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/11361/revisions). In retrospect, I should have remembered that the Chem FAQ was copied from the Physics FAQ (by me!) when I fixed [this](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220/typo-in-the-faq-list#comment344_221) and fixed it here as well.

Comment: Note that it may take some time to update for everyone.